# Device Orientation not working for my app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

I am having problem in implementing the device orientation methods. I am implementing it as

follows

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{


    return TRUE;

    }

    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    }
```

In tha appdelegate I am doing

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```

I want my app to work for all the orientations . But none of the orientation is working

properly.Any help ? My app is targeted IOS 4.3 , but it should also work for IOS 5 and 6 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in AppDelegate, write this. THIS IS VERY IMP

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Also, A lot depends on with which controller is your UIViewController embedded in.

Eg, If its inside UINavigationController, then you might need to subclass that UINavigationController to override orientation methods like this.

subclassed UINavigationController (the top viewcontroller of the hierarchy will take control of the orientation.) needs to be set it as self.window.rootViewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
     return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
 }
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
     return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
 }
```

From iOS 6, it is given that UINavigationController won't ask its UIVIewControllers for orientation support. Hence we would need to subclass it.

Comment: in my case - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window will alone do the trick fo me , I guess

Comment: because adding this alone gave me all the orientations.

Comment: Yes, if your viewcontroller is itself the root controller then this method only will make it work. Incase, your rootcontroller is UINavigationController then you need to subclass it! Otherwise its fine!

Comment: I want to know is there any need to add the (BOOL)shouldAutorotate and   (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations in the particular view controller ?

Comment: Yes, you need these methods, These methods would get called when your View gets created for the first time. If you don't want your view to rotate then don't write these methods.

Comment: and will this method work in IOS 4.3? Because it didn't seem to work for me . Should i add my old method - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
 return YES;
} for the app to support ios 4.3 ?

Comment: supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow is for AppWindow, while these methods are for your particular UIViewController

Comment: Yes PLEASE! For Versions < iOS 6, these methods don't work. You need to keep shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for supporting iOS Versions < 6.0